# Windows form freezing while executing hash of file

Tags: c#, file, user-interface, asynchronous, hash

My program downloads a file and verifies the hash of that file. While it is hashing the file, the windows forms UI freezes as the computer is cranking away at computing the hash.

No matter what I try, the UI freezes until the hashing of that file has completed. Is there any way to asynchronously hash without locking the GUI and making the user think the program has crashed

I also have tried a buffered hash as seen in the code

//main function called after a successful asynchronously file download completes

```
private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    String = help.getHash(*some file directory*);
}
```

//help class

```
public String getHash(String fileLoc)
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileLoc))
    {
        HashAlgorithm sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
        return BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

//I also have tried a buffered hash as follows

```
public String getHashBuffered(String fileLoc)
{
    using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileLoc), 1200000))
    {
        HashAlgorithm sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
        return BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: You need to compute it in a background thread.

Comment: Yeah, don't let this time-costly routine run on the UI thread. While this routine is running on the UI thread, the UI thread is blocked. A blocked UI thread won't do anything, no refreshes/updates to the UI, no processing of user input/interactions. (Delegate execution of getHash/getHashBuffered to a background thread. Or create and let a Task run the logic in getHash/getHashBuffered asynchronously; which behind the curtains would also cause your routine to be run on a background thread)

Comment: @SLaks: or in a foreground thread

Comment: what takes the time; computing the hash or downloading the file?

Comment: The download I’ve been able to make asynchronous, no GUI freeze. It’s the hashing that causes the freezing

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
public string GetHash(String fileLoc)
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileLoc))
    {
        HashAlgorithm sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
        return BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    }
}

private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var hash = await Task.Run(() => help.getHash(*some file directory*));
}
```